# MySQL to PHP arrays for phplot

Tags: php, mysql, phplot

I have the following query.

```
SELECT day, price, source FROM prices WHERE item_id = 5
```

Table looks like this

```
date | price | source
1    | 1     | source_1
2    | 2     | source_2
3    | 9     | source_1
3    | 7     | source_2
3    | 3     | source_3
```

Note that not every source has data for every "date". Some dates have multiple sources. This is for a price comparison graph powered by PHPlot.

The array for PHPlot needs to be like this.

```
$data = array(
 array('1', 1, 4, 2),
 array('2', 5, 7, 1),
 array('3', 7, '', 6),
 array('4', 8, 1, 4),
 array('5', 2, 4, 6),
 array('6', '', 4, 5),
 array('7', 7, 2, 3));
```

Notice that some data is missing for some sources. This is intended.

So what I need to do (I think) is to group the data in some way.

The final icing on the cake is the data labels...

```
$labels = array('source_1', 'source_2', 'source_3');
```

I'm ashamed to admit this is going over my head quite a bit, but I'm keen to learn. I have this working perfectly with only one "source".

Comment: can you shed a little more light on what PHPlot expects? I know you supplied some example arrays, but what are the elements supposed to represent?

Comment: @Alfie PHPlot expects two arrays. One with data, and one with the labels. For the "data" you have X-axis value then the Y-axis values associated with each X-axis value.

So to simplify, in my example we have array('1',1, 4, 2) which is DAY, source_1 value, source_2 value, source_3 value.

I barely understand it myself, so apologies if this is unclear

Comment: To confuse things further, an X-axis value (in my case a date) doesn't need to have multiple Y-axis values, providing the "missing" values are left blank.

Here is an "official" example, which may help with understanding: http://www.phplot.com/phplotdocs/start-multiple.html

Comment: ok.. can you also describe how you want your graph to look/what it should display? You want source_x on the y-axis and dates along the x-axis? where does the price fit in? sorry if i'm being stupid :)

Comment: So x-axis is the dates, correct. y-axis is the price (one "line" each source).

Comment: ok, and finally - you say you are using dates, but what you have written is just using incrementing integers for the date column.. is that right? :)

Comment: ok, well based on what I think - I am about to post a suggested solution..

Comment: alright - is that answer what you're after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok.. to make your data arrays, try this query:

```
SELECT `day`, `price`, `source` FROM prices WHERE `item_id` = 5 ORDER BY `day`, `source`
```

Then fetch an associative array from that result, and pass it to this function:

```
function makeArray($rows) {
    $rowCount = 0;
    $finalArray = array();
    $legendArray = array();

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $thisDate = (int)$row['day'];
        if ($thisDate > $rowCount) {
            $rowCount++;
            $finalArray[$rowCount-1] = array($thisDate, '', '', '');
        }
        if (!in_array($row['source'], $legendArray)) {
            $legendArray[] = $row['source'];
        }
        $thisIndex = 1;
        switch($row['source']) {
            case 'source_1':
                $thisIndex = 1;
                break;
            case 'source_2':
                $thisIndex = 2;
                break;
            case 'source_3':
                $thisIndex = 3;
                break;
        }
        $finalArray[$rowCount-1][$thisIndex] = $row['price'];
    }
    return array($legendArray, $finalArray);
}
```

Using your example data, here is the output when `print_r()`'ing the returned array:

```
Array 
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                Array 
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 1
                            [2] => 
                            [3] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [1] => 
                            [2] => 2
                            [3] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 3
                            [1] => 9
                            [2] => 7
                            [3] => 3
                        )

                )
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 'source_1'
                [1] => 'source_2'
                [2] => 'source_3'
            )
    )
```

Comment: Excellent work, I'm going to try this out on live data tomorrow morning. Impressive work, I shall update :)

Comment: Great - I wasn't sure if the total sources was fixed or not, as this won't cater to more than 3 sources as it is. also, The 'inner' arrays start at an index of 1: change $rowCount = 0 to $rowCount = -1 if you want them to start at 0. In fact, I will edit it for that as starting at 1 is not typical.

Comment: Total sources is fixed for now; I might add more in the future but it looks like a simple change to support that. Only thing I've just noticed is the zero values, PHPlot treats them as actual zeroes which affects the graph. Needs to be an empty value if possible.

Comment: ok no prob - just needs changing in the array initialisation. will update again :)

Comment: @DanielCrocker as all sources start with `source_` and end with an integer, you could just get that integer instead of doing a `switch` statement. For instance, you can `explode` using `source_` (you use it as a separator for creating an array) and then getting the second element from that array will give you the number. Something like `$number = explode('source_', $row['source']); $number = $number[1];`

Comment: @AlejandroIván Yes, I would do that too - but it still needs a little more modification to allow for the additional empty indices to be explicitly set to an empty string.

Comment: Then something like `$number = explode('source_', $row['source']); $number = count($number) == 2 ? $number[1] : '';` ?

Comment: @AlejandroIván but if some rows have 5 sources and others only 2, the rows with fewer sources will have missing elements.

Comment: You will need to find out the total maximum sources at some point, and then you can use that to fill in the gaps in the rows with fewer sources.

Comment: @DanielCrocker oops sorry - there was a problem with the way I made the index start at 0 and it has confused the results. I have edited (again) to fix :)

Comment: @Alfie finally got round to trying this, here it is in action: [link](http://vgdb.uk/images/priceHistory.jpg?gameId=1937&scale=2) - had to make one small change, because the "day" field is actually a timestamp. `$thisDate = date('j M Y', strtotime($row['timestamp']));` Not sure how that is going to effect things, but it's working.

Comment: @Alfie also the `$legend` array is currently hard-coded for demonstration of how it should look. Would be great to get that working, too. Really appreciate all the help by the way :)

Comment: @AlejandroIván Thanks for the suggestion, but this is just example date. Real "source" fields are quite varied.

Comment: @DanielCrocker Yes, it's looking good :) If your timestamps are only precise to the day then it should still work fine if using `$thisDate = $row['timestamp'];`. If the timestamps include time as well as date then this wouldn't work very well. Adding the legend is quite simple but the function will need changing to allow it to return multiple data. You could either use parameters passed by reference or wrap the two resulting arrays inside another. I will amend the example to show, but will use the 'wrapped array' method.

Comment: ok, updated. hope that's what you're after. I can't test it unfortunately because I'm at work, but pretty sure it should be good :)

Comment: @Alfie One tiny mistake in your code (missing bracket line 12) but you're doing it blind ;) It works! [see here](http://vgdb.uk/images/priceHistory.jpg?gameId=7729&scale=2) couldn't be happier, thanks. Will consider this well and truly answered!

Comment: @DanielCrocker Doh :) ty - have updated. I'm pleased it's all working though! Please mark the answer as accepted if you are happy. Cheers

Comment: @Alfie just noticed a little glitch. See the output [here](http://vgdb.uk/images/priceHistory.jpg?gameId=236&scale=2). You'll notice that the label colours don't match because the second source (uk.webuy.com) does not have any data. The orange triangle is representing the 3rd source, as the 2nd does not exist.

` [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => amazon.co.uk
            [1] => leveluponline.com
        )`

Comment: @DanielCrocker If I'm understanding correctly, adding a check for a non-empty price before adding to the `$legendArray` should be enough: `if ($row['price'] != '' && !in_array($row['source'], $legendArray)) {...` (it's getting quite difficult to help without a proper data set now though)

Comment: @DanielCrocker I'm thinking about what I suggested, and think there may be an edge case - if a source only has data on later rows, the order of the legend items may get mixed up. Let me think for a min

Comment: @Alfie I'm having trouble with the logic too, it's not an easy one. Happy to show you complete data in private, but I'm feeling you've already spent a fair bit of time on this conundrum!

Comment: @DanielCrocker Go for it, I'm happy to help - I'm a programmer, I like to problem solve :) I meant to get back to you here sooner, but have been unexpectedly busy with other stuff. I have a number of ways to solve it, but feel they're not very elegant so have been holding back until I had a chance to give it some proper thought.

Comment: @Alfie and [here's another example](http://vgdb.uk/images/priceHistory.jpg?gameId=79877&scale=2) where the labels are reversed... Which shouldn't even be possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112833/discussion-between-daniel-crocker-and-alfie).